# How to properly do pivot_wider?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I used pivot wider on a dataset where I had scores from block 1 and block 2:

```
library(tidyr)
dat_sim_f_wide <- dat_sim_f %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = block_order, values_from = score)
```

[image: the dataset view after running the code]

After running the code, the scores are not in the same rows (picture attached).

Running `drop_na()` doesn't help, as a result there is nothing in the dataset.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: pictures of data are not reproducible examples

Comment: pivot_wider will use the non-pivoted columns as keys. I presume in this case that `conf_condition` and/or `liking` do not match between blocks for each `Prolific_ID`, and/or not all `Prolific_ID` values have corresponding block1 and block2 values. If it's the first issue, you could try `values_from = c(conf_condition, liking, score)` so that those columns are treated as values to  output instead of key columns. Can you make a simpler example that demonstrates your issue, and share the data for your example as code we can run?